# nodejs mysql not using full config

Tags: node.js, knex.js, node-mysql

**First of all, I can't find any answers here and Google. I may search the wrong direction and appreciate any help.**

```
Node: 10.24.1/12.22.1/14.17.0/16.3.0 (These are the versions I tried)
Mysql for node: 2.18.1
Knex: 0.95.0/0.95.4/0.95.5 (Versions I tried)
Test environments: two computers (mac & win) in two networks (totally separated)
```

**Background**

The code needs to access the mysql database locally. This database has been tested through HeidiSQL(win) and Sequel Ace(mac) on those two computers with the same credentials *remotely* and *successfully*.

To avoid interference by other codes, I initiated a new project using `npm init`. It has one file: `app.js` and the code is below:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '123.123.123.123', // Remote database IP
  user     : 'user_name',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'mydb'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

`200.200.200.200` here is an example of the network's real IP
And the error is below:

```
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'user_name'@'200.200.200.200' (using password: YES)",
sqlState: '28000',
fatal: true
```

I then clone this mini test project to another computer and tested in a different network with example IP `202.202.202.202` and the error is below:

```
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'user_name'@'202.202.202.202' (using password: YES)",
sqlState: '28000',
fatal: true
```

Apparently the *username* has been adapted by the *mysql* library but the *host* is not. I assume that the *password* is taken in as well. because of the `using password: YES`.

I don't think this is related to the database because without using the correct IP, the code hasn't even touched the database server yet.

It looks like it's using `localhost` but shouldn't it be `192.168.x.x` and I don't use `localhost` anywhere.

I tried a few versions of node and looks like it's not related to node. `knex` and `mysql` are freshly installed using `npm`. Project is as clean as possible. I can't anywhere that has any problems could cause this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your database username and password. If it's working before then it should work now and I don't think it's related to node of any of your dependancies.

If it's never working, then try to change your password and try again. From your example the config is used by the mysql lib so there's no reason it picks your username and password but explicitly ignores your host.

Comment: I will try a new set of username and account. Thanks

Comment: You are right. I still don't know why it throws that kind of error but resetting username and password did work. Thanks